# Overloading Methods (Closed)

Tags: java, methods, int, double, overloading

answered. thank you

Please help, Ive been working on a program for quite a few hours straight now and I cannot understand how to incorporate overloading methods.

I'm trying to get a double to become an int through the overloading method, but i cannot get it to do so properly, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What ist your question?

Comment: Are you asking for what overloading methods is...?

Comment: how exactly am i suppose to incorporate 'method overloading' as the assignment requires?

Comment: @user3287957 By writing a class with two methods as described. Overloading means they have the same name but take different arguments.

Comment: i wrote a code without it I'm just stuck on how it was needed to be used.

Comment: You "wrote a code" that involves no methods. It would seem odd that you have an assignment from class that is asking you to do things that have never been covered in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An overloaded method essentially means that you are creating two methods with the same name but different parameters. Java will consider the two methods as different even though their name is the same.

For eg:

```
public static double interestcalc(double rate, int year){
    *Method Body*
}

public static double interestcalc(double principal){
    *Method Body*
}
```

When calling these two methods, depending on the parameters you use, java will either go to the method with `(double, in)` as parameters or the method with `(double)` as the parameter.

You can use this for your calculations. For example, you can use one method to get the user inputs (i.e. essentially copy the code for user inputs into a method) and use another method for the calculations. You overload methods by using different parameters

Cheers, and good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

> The Java programming language supports overloading methods, and Java
>   can distinguish between methods with different method signatures. This
>   means that methods within a class can have the same name if they have
>   different parameter lists (there are some qualifications to this that
>   will be discussed in the lesson titled "Interfaces and Inheritance").
>   Overloading methods provides flexibility to your program by allowing multiple types of entries, in this case, providing the loan amount as an `int` or a `double`.

I'd rather not give you code, but you seem like a pretty smart individual, so I think you can reason through this.

First of all, create a method that takes the following parameters:

- double interestRate
- int years
- int loaned

Create another method with the same parameters, except instead of int loaned, make it double loaned.

What your professor means is that since some may enter an integer and some a double for the loaned amount, it is important to make sure you will accept both types.

Comment: So in other words write the code twice (how it is asked of me to do). The way I'm understanding this is write the overloading methods to make sure to account for any and all variations of decimals from the user inputs?

Comment: You can make it even more flexible than writing it twice by, in your method that takes two ints, do `return myMethodName(interestRate, years, (double) loaned`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna go on a limb and assume that you want to know what overloading methods are:
Overloading methods are used to take in different kinds of arguments - either as a contingency or you truly need them i suppose - anyway, heres and example:

```
public double getAPrimitive(double aDouble){
  return aDouble;
}

public int getAPrimitive(int anInt){
  return anInt;
}
```

you see how they both have the same names- just different return types and arguments - useful, but please try not to use stack as a go to for learning java - you could go to java tutorials to learn more. :D

Comment: Sorry if it seems like that =/. I was just having a hard time understanding how the professor wanted us to use it. I understand method overloading, just really saw no point in doing it that way, which made the problem for me… but thank you!

Comment: if you find this helpful - plus 1 it, bro!

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not yet fully understand the use and function of methods, because your code does not contain any external method except for the main one.
The method concept, in short, is very simple. Think of it as a little robot that does the work for you!
At first, it will clean and improve your code, and It also has many advantages that you will find in the future.
The concept is taking all the calculations out of your main function and making them into a function, then calling the function from the main function.
The overloading is exactly as the other comments describe.
good luck!